# Count command in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

What information exactly the hdfs dfs -count  gives. It shows 3 columns in the output. What does this 3 columns signifies

**

```
hdfs dfs -count <path>
 **5         3603         2099476898    <path>**
```

**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output columns with -count are: DIR_COUNT, FILE_COUNT, CONTENT_SIZE, PATHNAME

[see details here - count](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#count)

Answer (score 0):

[Understanding HDFS Quotas](http://www.michael-noll.com/blog/2011/10/20/understanding-hdfs-quotas-and-hadoop-fs-and-fsck-tools/) helped me while I was trying to modify the quota.